# TAR and excluding directory files but kee directory

Tags: tar, exclude

Noob alert:

Can I exclude files in the directory "imagecache" but still make the directory a part of the TAR archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, just use `--exclude` for that purpose.

```
tar czf file.tar.gz --exclude '*/imagecache/*' files-or-directories-to-add
```

[`man tar`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar)

Comment: Just to be sure, will there still be the a empty directory called "imagecache" in the archive?

Comment: Yes, I've used this command yesterday. I've just tested this command, and it still works.